# Anuncio del tipo Interscroller

Tags: javascript, css

debido a la baja de un compañero me toca asumir la creación de un anuncio del tipo Interscroller como dice el propio título de la pregunta, más o menos lo tengo, salvo por el detalle de que en el contenido que se muestra por debajo se tiene que poder hacer click.
He montado una demo aquí: [demo interscroller](https://jsfiddle.net/a53t0dk2/)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.WebContent {
  background: lightgray;
  width: 100;
}

ul {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
}

#ads-wraper {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAC0lEQVQIW2NgAAIAAAUAAR4f7BQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
  height: 645px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">line 0</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 10</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 12</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 13</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 14</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 15</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 16</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 17</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 18</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 19</a></li>
  <li><a href="">line 20</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="WebContent">
  Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar
  textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem
  Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han <a href="">evolucionado</a> a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo
  insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
</div>
<div id="ads-wraper"></div>
<div class="WebContent">
  Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar
  textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem
  Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han <a href="">evolucionado</a> a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo
  insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
</div>
```

Pensaba que con pointer-events: none; en la imágen que hace de separador del contenido lo iba a solucionar pero como se puede ver en el ejemplo no es así.
Cualquier ayuda sera bienvenida, un saludo.

Comment: Haz que tu pregunta sea _específica_ (¿cuál es el problema?), y pon el código _en la pregunta_. La pregunta perderá su parte esencial si el enlace que apunta al código se llegara a romper. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: gracias por el consejo, en cuanto a la respuesta dada ya había visto esa solución pero como vi que está deprecated y cualquier día puede desaparecer, era por ver si había otra solución, ya veo que no, muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: @ardleon Bienvenido! No dejes de realizar el [tour] y de leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es implementar una combinación de elementos:

1. Una "envoltura" (*wrapper*) con posición relativa.
2. Un "contenedor" (*container*) con posición absoluta con [`clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/clip) para crear un recuador tipo "ventana".
3. Un elemento "contenido" (*content*) con posición fija para fijarlo al borde superior del viewport

#### Ejemplo:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
}

.WebContent {
  background: lightgray;
  width: 100;
}

.ads-wraper {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAC0lEQVQIW2NgAAIAAAUAAR4f7BQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 123456789; /* por ejemplo */
  display: block;
  height: 645px;
  min-height: 645px;
}

.ads-wraper>.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 100vw, 645px, 0); /* ciudado con el ancho */
}

.ads-wraper>.container>.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 645px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translateZ(0px);
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="WebContent">
  Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar
  textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem
  Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han <a href="">evolucionado</a> a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo
  insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
</div>
<div class="ads-wraper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">line 0</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 14</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 15</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 16</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 17</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 18</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 19</a></li>
        <li><a href="">line 20</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="WebContent">
  Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar
  textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem
  Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han <a href="">evolucionado</a> a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo
  insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
</div>
```